# The charge on an infinite grounded conducting plane induced by a nearby point charge

Tags: electrostatics

$Q$ is a point charge above the plane.

I wonder why is the induced charge $-Q$ and not  $-\dfrac{Q}{2}$ if the flux from point charge to the plane is: $$\Phi=\dfrac{\Theta}{4\pi}\dfrac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}}=\dfrac{2\pi}{4\pi}\dfrac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}}=\dfrac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$$

where $\Theta$ is a half sphere solid angle.

Thanks

PS: Please try to avoid using the method of images in the explanation, since that is where the result $-Q$ comes from.

Comment: Can you add details to your argument? Not clear how you arrive at your result of $Q/2$.

Comment: The opposite charge on the plane is induced by the flux of Electric field from the point charge. Half of the flux goes to the plane, half goes above it.

Comment: What theorem or law are you applying?

Comment: If you are applying the Gauss's law, and saying that flux equals charge enclosed, then you have to pay attention that the plane is not a closed surface (or only one half of a closed surface).

Comment: I do not recall any fundamental laws saying that charge induced  equals flux of the source charge (times $\epsilon_0$).

Comment: @velutluna Yes Gauss's law. Why isn't it a close surface? One side of the pill box is inside the conductor (flux through it is zero), the other side between the conductor and point charge with flux $-\dfrac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$ through it.

I might be doing something stupid, but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you state your law (or rule)? I know Gauss's law. But I don't see why it helps you arrive at the conclusion that (Flux on the upper surface of the pillbox due to the electric field of the source charge) = induced charge enclosed. PS Take $\epsilon_0=1$ for simplicity.

Comment: @velutluna Are you uncomfortable with flux on the upper surface of the pillbox being caused by charge outside of pillbox? Let's put the upper surface of the pillbox higher so the point charge is now enclosed inside. => Flux through upper side is now $\dfrac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$, the flux through the side inside conductor it is still zero.

Comment: Don't worry! I am very comfortable with that. But I just don't see why you have your law/rule that the flux due to the source charge outside should equal the induced charge inside.

Comment: Although I don't get your question at all, something may be helpful to solve your confusion, I am not sure. When you say the E field inside the conductor is zero and therefore the flux is zero, you are talking about the total E field, due to the source charge and the induced charges. The flux (through the pillbox surface inside the conductor) due to the induced charges is not zero.

Comment: @velutluna Yes, E field inside the conductor and the flux from all charges inside the pillbox (induced + point charge) through the surface inside the conductor must be zero (otherwise it wouldn't be static system).

Comment: OK. My answer will be: The OP has the rule in mind that the flux due to the source charge on the pillbox surface outside the conductor should equal the induced charge enclosed by the pillbox, which he claimed to come from the Gauss's law. But I have completely no idea where this rule come from. Hope some body else can help...

Comment: @velutluna Sorry for being tiresome. Do we agree on the total flux $\dfrac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$ from the pillbox (with the point charge and one side of the conductor inside the pillbox)? Then the charges inside the pillbox must produce this flux in accordance with Gauss law. There is $Q$ inside we know about => there must be some other charge $-\dfrac{Q}{2}$ to compensate it.

Comment: By total flux do you mean the flux due to the total E field (source charge and induced charge)? If yes, then my answer is NO. The source charge producs a negative flux, while the induced surface charges produce the other half.

Comment: Outside the conductor, the source charge produces a flux, the induced charges produces equal flux, in the same direction, so they add up. Inside the conductor, the source charge produces a flux, the induced charges produce an equal flux, but in opposite direction, and so they cancel.

Comment: @velutluna Thank you, I think I see my mistake. Just to be clear what is the total flux (from source and induced charges) from the upper surface of the pillbox (above the conductor and point charge)? You said that flux add up, I think it should cancel also.. So the total flux through the whole pillbox is zero and induced $-Q$ cancels with source $Q$.

Comment: No. Above the conductor, the flux due to the positive source charge is downward, so is that due to the induced negative charges. So they add up. Below they do cancel.

Comment: You're talking about area between point charge and the conductor? I was talking about area above both the point charge and the conductor.

Comment: You said pillbox, which in my understanding is a very thin box. By the way, if your pillbox is not thin, why can you ignore the flux on the lateral curved surface? OK, if your pillbox is very large, then you can do that. Then my answer will be the two fluxes cancel on both the top and the bottom. So that solves your problem?

Comment: @velutluna Yes, I've pushed the two other sides in limit to infinity. Thank you for your time and sorry for my stupidity. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The charge distribution on the conductor is such that the horizontal component of the field vanishes. If you write out the condition $\vec{\nabla} . \vec{E}_{//}=\sigma$ and integrate $\sigma$ over the entire plane then you should find $-Q$ as the answer independent of the distance of $Q$ to the plane. Of course you could also argue that a charge of $-Q$ at distance $r$ below the plane also exactly cancels $\vec{E}_{//}$, which is the basis of the image charge method.